# I am trying to create sockets with different URLs. How can i handle failed connections?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have a database in which there are different hosts on which i want to connect to through SSL. Because the hosts sometimes are random and often invalid i get an error at the point where the socket is created. I don't know how i can handle this problem

```
for(int i=connect.getMinId();i<connect.getMaxId();i++){
    System.out.println(connect.getHost(i));
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(URL, 443);
    socket.startHandshake();
    SSLSession session = socket.getSession();
}
```

Comment: why is that happening: _the hosts sometimes are random and often invalid_ ? Anyway, why don't you simply catch the exception? and continue to the next iteration (next host)?

Comment: It is because i am trying to run an SSL Observatory. The hosts are taken from very large network scan performed in the past. The hosts may not be working any more etc

Comment: First you have to say how you *want* to handle the failed connections: log errors? silently skip them? put them in a list to try again later? count them? Then it becomes straightforward to implement that.

Comment: I want to silently skip them. I have tried to catch the exception but sometimes the process gets stacked inside SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(URL, 443);

Comment: The question is: how can i skip a particular host that is trying to create a socket for a long period? Shall i use threads and set the time or is there any other way to make sure that a socket is implementable before the actual creation of the socket?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an unconnected Socket with `new Socket()`.
2. Connect it with a timeout using `Socket.connect(address, timeout)`. You can choose your own timeout up to the platform default. Note that the Javadoc incorrect says that 0 means an infinite timeout. It doesn't: it means the platform default, which is around a minute, dependent on the, err, platform. This method throws `SocketTimeoutException` if the timeout expires.
3. Wrap it in an `SSLSocket` with `SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket, host, port, true)`. Note that you have to re-specify the host and port: this is for SSL session sharing purposes; it doesn't create a new connection.
4. Get the session, or start the handshake. Note that getting the session starts the handshake, you don't have to do both. If you're not interested in the server certificate you don't really need to do this step at all.
5. Catch all IOExceptions and close the socket.

Comment: It was exactly what i wanted for my case thanks! Can you suggest me an efficient way to integrate threads in order to obtain certificates simultaneously?

Comment: Eh? Obtain what certificates? What does 'integrating threads' have to do with it? Sounds like a new question, and not a clear one. Try again.